# Mixing cin and getline under Linux and Windows

Tags: c++, windows, linux, getline, cin

I am aware of the common problem with mixing cin and getline. I believe this is different.

This is the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int a;
  string line;
  cin >> a;
  printf("A is '%d'\n", a);
  getline(cin, line);
  printf("Line is '%s'\n", line.c_str());
  cout << cin.fail() << cin.eof() << cin.bad() << endl;
}
```

I also have a version written using istream::getline. I believe the results are the same in all input cases given here.

```
a.out < test1
A is '1'
'ine is ' abc 2
000

a.out < test2
A is '1'
Line is ' abc 2'
000
```

where test1 is `$'1 abc 2\r\n'` (9 bytes) and test2 is `$'1 abc 2\n'` (8 bytes).

I haven't explicitly done these tests under Windows, but I have a hunch that the output is "as intended" i.e. same as output of test 2.

My question is: explain the output of test 1.
For example: why is printf output corrupt; is there a portability issue related to interpretation of line endings; how can the code be fixed with minimal change in logic.

Comment: You're discarding the result of the input operations, so there's no point speculating. Write correct code first, and *then* we can ask questions. As it stands this is a waste of time.

Comment: @Kerrek SB I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: You are discarding the result of `cin >> a;`. That's a serious programming error.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but _don't not mix `printf` and cout_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Linux, `getline` removes `\n` from the input stream. However, it does not remove the `\r`.

The *carriage return* (`\r`) **return**s the cursor to the beginning of the current line. So in the `printf` call, the STDOUT cursor is returned to the beginning of the line when it sees the `\r`. The next character it prints is the `'`, which overwrites the first character on the line (the `L`).

You do not see this behavior when there is no `\r` in the file.

Easy solution to fix this problem: manually check for `\r` when running under Linux and Unix.

Comment: That makes sense. Somehow I have not encountered this problem in years (except in other languages).

Comment: You are much better off using `cout` and `endl` when using C++. You'll avoid these platform-dependent issues in most cases.