# Error with reading file in Linux

Tags: c++, parsing

In my program, I take two file names from the command line arguments using the following code:

```
ifstream routesFile (arv[1]);
ifstream citiesFile (arv[2]);
```

I then proceed to read through the file and grab the data. Both files are CSVs:

```
while(citiesFile.good()){
        string city;
        string country;
        string xString;
        string yString;
        getline(citiesFile, country, ',');
        getline(citiesFile, city, ',');
        getline(citiesFile, xString, ',');
        getline(citiesFile, yString);
...
}
```

When I do this in Visual Studio using hard-coded file names, it works fine. When I use the command line argument in linux after using g++, it can open the files correctly but after that it has a lot of errors. To test the file reading, I printed out some of the read values which resulted in

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  map::at
hereELF
Òœc½Å¹jn!ýô (EÕL˜C
```

The appearance of `here` is due to actually being printed in the program. It doesn't arise from the error, I manually printed it to test the code.

It seems to not be able to read the data correctly. In the file for citiesFile, there are always 4 values per line, each separated by a single command, no spaces, and a new line character separates lines in the file. As I said above, it works fine in Visual Studio so I don't think it's a problem with the actual data, just reading it.

Comment: When does the error occur?

Comment: If I try to read in the information, it misinterprets it as the stuff shown. Then when I access various data structures using it, it throws out of bounds exception. The error doesn't occur if I hardcode the file names.

Answer (score 0):

Linux and window has different new line symbol. Linux '\n', windows '\r\n'. If you just copied the file into linux, you need to handle these in your program. You can look at [Mixing cin and getline under Linux and Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003521/mixing-cin-and-getline-under-linux-and-windows) as a reference.

Comment: I thought that getline without a third argument automatically used '\n' as its delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply moved the Windows files to Linux, check out the tool **dos2unix** to convert the file and fix the line endings. "EOL" in your output is a sign that something might be wrong with the endings.

http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html

Comment: When I use the command `dos2unix route.txt route1.txt` it returns an error code of 2, saying that route.txt is not a regular file.